# Having trouble with the variant of the "Two Sum" coding challenge?

Tags: python, algorithm

The two problems seeks to find two elements `x` and `y` such that `x+y=target`. This can be implemented using a brute force approach.

```
for x in arr:
    for y in arr:
        if x+y==target:
             return [x,y]
```

We are doing some redundant computation in the for loop -- that is we only want to consider combinations of two elements. We can do a `N C 2` dual-loop as follows.

```
for i, x in enumerate(arr):
    if y in arr[i+1:]:
        if x+y==target:
             return [x,y]
```

And we save a large constant factor of time complexity. Now let's note that inner most loop is a search. We can either use a hash search or a binary search for.

```
seen = set()
for i, x in enumerate(arr):      
    if target-x in seen:
        y = target-x
        return [x,y]
    seen.add(x)
```

Not that seen is only of length of `i`. And it will only trigger when hit the second number (because it's complement must be in the set).

A variant of this problem is: to find elements that satisfy the following `x-y = target`. It's a simple variant but it adds a bit of logical complexity to this problem.

My question is: why does the following not work? That is, we're just modifying the previous code?

```
seen = set()
for i, x in enumerate(arr):      
    for x-target in seen:
        y = x-target
        return [x,y]
    seen.add(x)
```

I've asked a friend, however I didn't understand him. He said that subtraction isn't associative. We're exploiting the associative property of addition in the two sum problem to achieve the constant time improvement. But that's all he told me. I don't get it to be honest. I still think my code should work. Can someone tell me why my code doesn't work?

Comment: `for target-y in seen` - that is not a thing in Python.

Comment: `for y-target in seen: return [x,y]` doesn't make _any_ sense because: 1) there's no function to return from; 2) you can't return from a function multiple times in a row; 3) `y-target` is nonsense as well as you can't have math expressions here: `for [no-math-here] in stuff:`.

Comment: Sorry there was a typo. I've fixed it now

Comment: `for target-x in seen` is still not a thing in Python.

Comment: You cannot use the operator `-` in the names of variables. You'll get a `SyntaxError: can't assign to operator`.

Comment: Do you mean `if target-x in seen`?

Comment: For this problem, you don't need an inner loop. Given a value of `x`, you can just check directly if `target - x` is in `arr` (and if `target - x == x`, make sure `x` appears twice in `arr`, perhaps).

Comment: You get a `SyntaxError` for both `for target-x in seen:` and `for x-target in seen:`.

Comment: Assuming you do mean `if target-x in seen:`, can you give an example of inputs that don't find the correct solution?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean

Comment: I sorta understand why it can't find it. But I can't put my finger on  how to describe it.

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm (once the `if`/`for` mixup is fixed) still doesn't work because subtraction is not commutative. The algorithm only effectively checks `x`,`y` pairs where `x` comes later in the array than `y`. That's OK when it's testing `x+y = target`, since it doesn't matter which order the two values are in. But for `x-y = target`, the order does matter, since `x - y` is not the same thing as `y - x`.

A fix for this would be to check each number in the array to see if it could be either `x` or `y` with the other value being one of the earlier values from `arr`. There needs to be a different check for each, so you probably need two `if` statements inside the loop:

```
seen = set()
for n in arr:      
    if n-target in seen:
        x = n
        y = n-target
        return [x,y]

    if n+target in seen:
        x = n+target
        y = n
        return [x,y]

    seen.add(x)
```

Note that I renamed the loop variable to `n`, since it could be either `x` or `y` depending on how the math worked out. It's not strictly necessary to use `x` and `y` variables in the bodies of the `if` statements, you could do those computations directly in the `return` statement. I also dropped the unneeded `enumerate` call, since the single-loop versions of the code don't use `i` at all.

Comment: Thanks. This is an interesting dynamic that I'm having trouble digesting.

Comment: I wonder how this looks if this was an arbitrary function. For example `sub(x, y)` is a function. Say we had some arbitrary function `k=f(x,y)`. How would this look? Would we need to use calculus?

Comment: To use the one-loop algorithm, you'd need an inverse function `y = f_inv(k, x)`. If `f(x, y)` is not the same as `f(y, x)`, you also need `x = f_inv2(k, y)`.

Comment: Why the inverse and not take the derivative?

Comment: I don't see how the derivative would be any help.

Comment: We need to use gradient descent to find the optimal values of Y against the discrete set

Comment: That sounds like a fundamentally different problem that what you described above (where `x` and `y` both come from `arr`). You should ask a separate question about it.